# text in textview seems to be in white color in real device but in emulator is OK

Tags: android-emulator, textview, android-2.2-froyo, android

The properties in a vertical layout are

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buscador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/searchcity"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/climaB" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In the Eclipse emulator for Android 3.0, the submitted text is perfectly seen but in my Android Froyo tablet it is not >:( . The app has minimun SDK = 8. Somebody had the same issue? What can be going on ? I also tried with Plain text TextView but in this case there was not problem neither of both, emulator and device. Sorry, forget to mention that the text in the textview is in color white when run the app in the Tablet, in the emulator is visible in dark color (black).

Comment: still unclear on what your problem is. Please try to be a little more specific. Maybe post some pictures?

Comment: ok, the project when tested in the Eclipse emulator run as expected, when I type in the textview, the word is seen written. When I test the same project in tablet with Android Froyo, the color of the text in the textview is not seen (because it is white and background is white too). The question is why, the text is seen in dark color in emulator but not in the Tablet. In the last case, I can see the text written if I select the text (and background is in orange color). I didn't touch the default text and background styles when I added those views.

Comment: try adding these two lines in your linear layout tag--> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools

Comment: both of these are already in the layout xml. Now, I've tried to delete view background property in Graphical Layout but it is set automatically after I delete it :(

Comment: why dont you just change the background color to black or something else. that way your problem will be solved.

Comment: In this afternoon I did that, and it works. But the issue itself remains unsolved. I think it has to do with compatibility among different api levels. My project is intended to run from api 8 to 19, maybe not all styles are considered in the folders res/values-vxx then this kind of bugs could appear. Try yourself.

Comment: well maybe you are right but i am glad that your problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 1):

For Tablet and some android versions default Text Color is white , That is why you are getting white text color, add android:textColor attribute

Answer (score 0):

check if you have dark mode on. If yes try again after disabling it.